# How to handle django grouped choices?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

Having this kind of django choices:

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
    ('Audio', (
        ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
        ('cd', 'CD'),
    )
    ),
    ('Video', (
        ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
        ('dvd', 'DVD'),
    )
    ),
    ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
)
```

How do I access the subgroup of a category (e.g. get the audio choices)? How do I iterate over the set?, and how can I directly get a leaf node such as Vinyl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in type `dict` can be constructed from a list of tuples.

```
>>> MEDIA_CHOICES_D = dict(MEDIA_CHOICES)
>>> MEDIA_CHOICES_D.keys()
['unknown', 'Audio', 'Video']
>>> audio = MEDIA_CHOICES_D['Audio']
>>> audio
(('vinyl', 'Vinyl'), ('cd', 'CD'))
>>> audio_d = dict(audio)
>>> audio_d['vinyl']
'Vinyl'
>>> for k, v in audio_d.iteritems(): print '%s -> %s' % (k, v)
... 
vinyl -> Vinyl
cd -> CD
>>>
```